# How to find GCD of those two complex polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I have a polynomial

$$f(x) = i(x^2-1)^3+(x^2+1)^3-8x^3$$

I want to check if this has repeated roots. To do so, I'll find greatest common divisor (euclidean algorithm) of $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$.

$$f(x) = i(x^2-1)^3+(x^2+1)^3-8x^3 = i(x^6-3x^4+3x^2-1)+(x^6+3x^4+3x^2+1)-8x^3$$

$$f'(x) = i(6x^5-12x^3+6x)+(6x^5+12x^3+6x)-24x^2$$

I know I should find the GCD as $(x-i)(x-1)$ but this is where I'm stuck. What would the next step be?

Comment: [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_algorithm) for gcd of polynomials.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I have no clue how to apply it on those.

Comment: How to do this using long polynomial division?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspection, $f(1)=0$ so $x-1$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

Since $f'(x)= 3i(x^2-1)^2(2x)+3(x^2+1)^2(2x)-24x^2$, we also have that $f'(1)=0$, so $x-1$ is a factor of $f'(x)$.

This means $(x-1)^2$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

---

One also has that by inspection $f(i)=0$ so $x-i$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

We also have that $f'(i)=0$, so $x-i$ is a factor of $f'(x)$.

So we also have that $(x-i)^2$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

Comment: How to prove those algebraically? For instance, long polynomial division?

Comment: @Enzo : That would certainly work, but you would have to group all of the terms of the same degree together and you would be faced with division of complex numbers which is easy but unwieldy.

Comment: The thing I'm still confused about is where to stop dividing those polynomials.

Comment: @Enco Note that this isn't a *complete* answer since we still need to check if the remaining quadratic factor has repeated roots. Did you intend to use only the GCD method, or are other ad-hoc methods admissable?  The GCD method is the best way to proceed in general.

Answer (score 1):

It's best not to split the polynomials up using $i$, but collect terms in powers of $x$.

$$ \eqalign{f_0 = f(x) &=  \left( 1+i \right) {x}^{6}+ \left( 3-3\,i \right) {x}^{4}-8\,{x}^{3}+
 \left( 3+3\,i \right) {x}^{2}+1-i \cr
f_1 = f'(x) &=  \left( 6+6\,i \right) {x}^{5}+ \left( 12-12\,i \right) {x}^{3}-24\,{x
}^{2}+ \left( 6+6\,i \right) x
}
$$
The remainder of $f_0$ on division by $f_1$ is 
$$  f_2 = f_0 - (x/6) f_1 = \left( 1-i \right) {x}^{4}-4\,{x}^{3}+ \left( 2+2\,i \right) {x}^{2}+
1-i
$$
Then take remainder of $f_1$ on division by $f_2$, etc.